# DynamoDB design for storing time and hours

Tags: time, range, amazon-dynamodb

I have a requirement to store range of time. For example I want to know if an event is triggered between start time and end time everyday. Say if an user logged-in between 6am-10am & 4pm-8pm. I am planning to use the following json for a new Attribute to store this range.

```
"duration-timestamp": [
      {
         "start_time" : "360"
         "end_time" : "600"
      }, 
      {
         "start_time" : "960"
         "end_time" : "1200"
      }
   ]
```

Although my code can handle this, unsure if this is the elegant way to handle it.

NOTE: I cannot create new item for start_time and end_time as I want to capture this array of time for a single item.

EDIT 1 :

- I can have multiple events like the one mentioned above. It could be seeing who logged in only saturday and sunday.
- I am not looking at ways for querying. Will add a gsi to achieve that.
- 360 translates to 6am. It is represented in minutes.
- Logic would be written around this , so trying to understand if this is the would be the right way to store
- Yes, planning to use Maps

Comment: You will need to be more clear about the questions. Are you only looking for a way to store the data or you will need to write queries for these data and how often will this data be queried. For storing it on DynamoDB level you can use list of maps i.e. field for **duration-timestamp** and map for fields inside (**start_time** and **end_time**) or you can just strigify the JSON and store it as strings in dynamoDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain how 360 to 600 corresponds to the 6am to 10am, but that aside - AWS released a new tool in January - their AWS EC2 instance scheduler tool.

One thing they do is provide a dynamodb table that, among other things, lets you specify begin and end time schedules for when instances will be turned on and off.

They use a slightly different format, for example:

```
{
  "description": {
    "S": "Office hours"
  },
  "begintime": {
    "S": "14:00"
  },
  "endtime": {
    "S": "18:00"
  },
  "name": {
    "S": "office-hours"
  },
  "type": {
    "S": "period"
  },
  "weekdays": {
    "SS": [
      "mon-fri"
    ]
  }
}
```

Not that everything AWS is correct for all uses-cases, but here is an example of an internal team looking at a problem similar to yours, and how they solved it.

Maybe reviewing their documentation for this particular tool will help you design your solution:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/solutions-reference/aws-instance-scheduler/latest/instance-scheduler.pdf

Comment: This is helpful. Thank you !